# How to set Preference-->Editor-->external tools to visual studio programatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, automation, sonarqube

I have a requirement to run sonar scan for Unity project, As it is C#, we need to have .sln file. I use to run external method query to generate .sln file. But, To get that, we need to have VS selected as external tools under editor. But if we install new editor, we have to do it manually again.

Is there any possibilities to automate this? How can I set VS as external tools for every editor automatically ?

we have to do it manually again.